# In $1 < k < n-10^6$, what is $k$? (details in question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

This is a homework question of mine, I am not searching for the solution but rather what it means. It seems pretty straight forward but I am a little confused as to what the $k$ in $1 < k < n-10^6$ is supposed to be.

Here is the question: 
 Consider the number $n = 2^{1000000000000000000000000000000000} + 1$ . Suppose that it is known that none of the numbers $1 < k < n-10^6$ divide $n$ . Does it follow that $n$ is a prime number?

Again I am not asking for solutions but rather what values $k$ may take.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The statement $1 \lt k \lt n-10^6$ shows the range of $k$. It can range from $2$ to a million and one below $n$. You are given that *no* $k$ in this range divides $n$.

Comment: oh right of course! Thanks

Comment: so then we cannot say whether or not n is a prime just because the values 1 < k < n−10^6 do not divide n right?

Comment: Yes we can, for the $n$ under consideration.  If one of those numbers divides $n$, what is the quotient?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but n is only a prime if the values 1 < k < n/2 do not divide n right?

Comment: That is true.  The upper limit can be reduced to $\sqrt n$, which is the point of my last comment.  Can you see why?

Comment: Ooh because n - 10^6 is still greater than √n right?

Comment: No, $10^{-6}$ is *much less* than $\sqrt n$ for this problem. $\sqrt {2^k}=2^{\frac k2}$ For large $k$, $2^k-10^6 \gg 2^{k-1}$